# Funtoo keychain - how to avoid blocking i3 login?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, i3, ssh-agent, keychain

I'm using Funtoo `keychain` on Ubuntu 22.04 and I have followed the instructions to add the following to `~/.profile`:

```
eval `keychain --eval --agents ssh id_rsa`
```

I'm running the i3 window manager, from GDM, and the problem is that GDM seems to run `/bin/bash /etc/gdm3/Xsession i3`, which invokes my `~/.profile` script. This causes it to hang on the `eval` line because it prompts for a password. Since there's no interactive shell I can't add one and the whole log-in process stops with a blank screen.

To recover I have to edit `~/.profile` to remove the keychain line, and manually restart GDM.

Is there an effective way to not have this log-in process blocked, but still have keychain ask me for a passphrase the first time I actually open a shell window in i3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that moving the keychain initialisation to `~/.bashrc` seems to solve the problem I was having at login-time:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# keychain - moved from .profile to avoid blocking i3 login
eval $(/usr/bin/keychain --quiet --nogui --eval --agents ssh $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

This does result in keychain running `--eval` mode for every terminal that I open, but it does seem to work.